# Storybook breaks after TypeScript upgrade (v3 to v4)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, storybook

After upgrading TypeScript from 3.9.6 to 4.4.4, our storybook breaks with the several errors similar to this one:

```
ERROR in ../pilot-mock-service/dist/mocks/image.js 3:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { generateRandomInteger, generateRandomString, removeNullValues } from './mock.utils';
| export class ImagePilotData {
>     alt;
|     caption;
|     credit;
 @ ../pilot-mock-service/dist/mocks/index.js 61:0-41 61:0-41
 @ ./stories/pages/qa/Post Page/postPagePrague.stories.tsx
 @ ./stories sync \.stories\.tsx$
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js
 @ multi ../node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ../node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/preview.js ../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
```

Some details about our project that might be relevant:

- We're using:

  - yarn workspaces
  - Storybook 5.3.19 (@storybook/addon-info @storybook/addon-knobs @storybook/addon-links @storybook/addon-viewport @storybook/addons @storybook/react)
  - React 16.13
  - Webpack 4
  - Babel 7
  - eslint 6

Dependencies in the problematic (yarn) workspace:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
        "aphrodite": "^2.2.3",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "consent-string": "^1.4.1",
        "current-device": "^0.10.0",
        "iframe-resizer": "^4.3.2",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
        "luxon": "^1.22.0",
        "mm-client-core": "1.0.0",
        "mm-theme-configuration": "1.0.0",
        "mm-ui-components": "1.0.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "traffic-source-analyzer": "1.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.1",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
        "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.21",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
        "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.19",
        "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
        "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
        "@types/iframe-resizer": "^3.5.8",
        "@types/luxon": "^1.21.0",
        "@types/nock": "^11.1.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.0",
        "@types/storybook__addon-info": "^5.2.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
        "core-js": "^3.4.7",
        "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-config-mm": "git+https://github.com/FTBpro/eslint-config-mm.git#v3.1",
        "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
        "jest": "^24.0.0",
        "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
        "mm-pilot-mock": "1.0.0",
        "nock": "^11.7.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.1",
        "typescript": "4.4.4",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
    }
}
```

I've tried virtually every possible solution I could find, to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch to storybook v6.1 or above.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562201/how-to-fix-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-currentl

Comment: Thanks Ritik, upgrading to storybook 6 (6.5) indeed fixed this error. However, it created a host of new errors  I've managed to solve some of them, but am now stuck on one :\
I'll open a new thread for that particular error.

Comment: I am adding the answer, please mark it so that other facing same issue do the needful.

Comment: Yeah @LiranH if this solved your issue please consider upvoting and accepting Ritik's answer to reward his effort and help other people facing this issue. (I don't know of this particular issue and don't want to vote on something I don't understand well - but since it seems from your comment like it solved your issue, please consider it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to storybook v6.1 or above.

Latest is v6.7, v6.6 or v6.5 would fix the issue.